# Account temporarily unavailable due to bad or missing auth token

Tags: cloudkit, xcode13.3.1

I got this message "Account temporarily unavailable due to bad or missing auth token" when I try to save to privateDatabase in CloudKit, using the CKDatabase.save(record:completionHandler).

It looks like the error that was posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557266/ios15-b4-nspersistentcloudkitcontainer-account-temporarily-unavailable-error) on stackoverflow has reappeared.

The fix for that other problem was a bug in Apple's side.

Anyone have this problem recently and have a solution?

Answer (score 6):

You might find it strange, When I got this error,

1. I went to settings, I did it in Simulator
2. Profile Section
3. Entered password.

After this, When I called the iCloud API again, It worked.

[image]

Comment: Yess! Login in simulator worked. I needed to edit public database, so I logged in with my dev id. I think Apple mentions this somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this repeatedly all of a sudden on an account that had worked fine before. Shutting things down and restarting didn't help.

This is xcode 13.3.1 using a simulator.

I went to the simulator menu: "Device" => "Erase all content and settings". I then logged in again via settings on the simulator. And then it was fine.